# Laravel 4 Dealing with Mass Assignment and Getting every lastInsertedId?

Tags: laravel, query-builder

I'm trying to insert an array of contacts, and then I need to insert each of them on a pivot table... Is there any clever way on solving this?

```
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {

        (DB::table('contacts')->insert($this->contacts()) );

       //I need also to insert every contact on my group_contacts pivot table...

        DB::table('group_contacts')->insert([
                "company_id" => $this->company,
                "group_id" => $this->group,
                "contact_id" => DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId()
            ]);

        DB::commit();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        //TODO: Listener for $e on saving.
        DB::rollback();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of inserting the whole array at once do it 1 contact at a time and save the fluent object to a local variable.

Then use the resulting objects id when you save the pivot data.

Answer (score 0):

- To get every last inserted id, just assign the result of insertion to a variable: e.g. $transaction = DB::table(...)->insert. Hopefully you will get $transaction->id in your case.
- I haven't come up with ways on Mass Assignment in laravel. Maybe you should try to insert the data simply by using database script. At least that's my way.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Abba Bryant, save one contact at the time and do further work with the contact object.

Then you could do something like this:

```
$contact->group()->attach($this->group);
```

More on many-to-many relationships and inserting or updating the pivot values can be found in this article: http://vegibit.com/many-to-many-relationships-in-laravel/